# R regex extract numbers from string depending of context

Tags: r, regex

```
s <- c('abc_1_efg', 'efg_2', 'hi2jk_lmn', 'opq')
```

How can I use a regex to get the numbers that are beside at least one underscore ("_"). In effect I would like to get outputs like this :

```
> output # The result
[1] 1 2
> output_l # Alternatively
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: The actual numbers or indices?

Comment: I hope that both solutions could count as one question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use regex lookarounds

```
grep("(?<=_)\\d+", s, perl = TRUE)
grepl("(?<=_)\\d+", s, perl = TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get just *indices*, use `grep` with a simple TRE regex (no lookarounds are necessary):

```
> grep("_\\d+", s)
[1] 1 2
```

To get the *numbers themselves*, use a PCRE regex with a positive lookahead with `regmatches` / `gregexpr`:

```
> unlist(regmatches(s, gregexpr("(?<=_)[0-9]+", s, perl=TRUE)))
[1] "1" "2"
```

**Details**:

- `(?<=_)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `_` to appear immediately to the left of the current position
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits

**EDIT**: If the digits to the left of `_` should also be considered, use 1) [`"(^|_)\\d|\\d(_|$)"`](https://regex101.com/r/POPyWR/1) with `grep` solution and 2) [`"(?<![^_])\\d+|\\d+(?![^_])"`](https://regex101.com/r/POPyWR/2) with the number extraction solution.

Comment: I added the solution for all these  scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Using this regex :

```
[_]([0-9]){1}
```

And selecting group 1 you'll get your digit, if you want more, use

```
[_]([0-9]+)
```

And it will not match the last two strings

You can use this tool : https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

with stringr:

```
s <- c('abc_1_efg', 'efg_2', 'hi2jk_lmn', 'opq', 'a_1_b')
library(stringr)
which(!is.na(str_match(s, '_\\d|\\d_')))
# [1] 1 2 5
```